# 0 records found PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database-connection, rets

I am talking with a MLS server and I'm pretty sure that I am on it. It just won't give me any arrays back.
I am logged on successfully
I pulled the Array of Listings Here are two that you may need to know.
[LIST_10] => Begin Date 
[LIST_15] => Status

**This worked**

```
if($connect) {
    /* Get table layout */
    $fields = $rets->SearchQuery("Property", "A");

    /* Take the system name / human name and place in an array */
    $table = array();
    foreach($fields as $field) {
        $table[$field['SystemName']] = $field['LongName'];
    }

    /* Display output */
    print_r($table);
    $rets->Disconnect();
}
}
```

**This returns 0 Records Found**

```
if($connect) {

    $sixmonths = date('c', time()-15778800); // get listings updated within last 6 months

    /* Search RETS server */
    $search = $rets->SearchQuery(
        'Property',                             // Resource
        "A",                                        // Class
        '((LIST_10>='.$sixmonths.'+),(LIST_15=ACT))',   // DMQL, with SystemNames
        array(
            'Format'    => 'COMPACT-DECODED',
            'Select'    => 'LIST_0,LIST_1,LIST_34,LIST_39,LIST_40,LIST_0,LIST_133',
            'Count'     => 1,//0 no record count, data  1 record count + data  2 record count, no data
            'Limit'     => 20
        )
    );

    /* If search returned results */
    if($rets->TotalRecordsFound() > 0) {
        while($data = $rets->FetchRow($search)) {
            print_r($data);
        }
    }
}
```

I am using this tutorial: http://dangodesign.net/2013/01/getting-started-with-rets-for-php/
Is there any information that would help more?

Answer (score 1):

Change your DMQL from:

```
'((LIST_10>='.$sixmonths.'+),(LIST_15=ACT))'
```

To:

```
'((LIST_10='.$sixmonths.'+),(LIST_15=ACT))'
```

You don't need a > sign in your query that is what the + sign means. I found this site to have a nice introduction to DMQL queries: [FlexMLS](https://www.flexmls.com/developers/rets/tutorials/dmql-tutorial/)

If you are able to connect with PHPRETS then you just need to try and change the following query and try to process the results.

Can you please paste the metadata online somewhere?

Comment: I don't have any HTML on the pages yet. Both of them have the same starting code. `<?php @include_once('PHP/phrets.php'); ?>

<?php
// LOGIN INFO//

$login = '###/Login';
$un = 'wwm.rets.###';
$pw = '#####';
$rets = new PHRETS;

$connect = $rets->Connect($login, $un, $pw);
if($connect) {...`

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what I am doing I have never done anything with php all I know is HTML, CSS, JQuery and how to follow tutorials. So that being said: I just noticed on the activity monitor when I FTP to the host that this comes up

Comment: `Status: Retrieving directory listing...  Command: TYPE I  Response: 200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary  Command: PASV  Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode(#,#,#,#) Command:MLSD  Response: 150 Accept data connection  Respose:226-Options: -a -l Response:226 18 matches total  status: Directory listing successful` Sorry I can't get them to go on their own lines

Comment: I don't want the code or anything. I want the metadata for Property and specifically the columns/fields you are trying to query.

Answer (score 0):

Change your DMQL from:

```
'((LIST_10>='.$sixmonths.'+),(LIST_15=ACT))'
```

to:

```
'(LIST_10>={$sixmonths}+),(LIST_15=ACT)'
```

Also make sure the field names are correct and try using Standard Names instead of System Names.

Comment: :( It didn't fix the problem

Comment: Is is'(LIST_#=thisPart)' standard or do I have to query to find the correct options. because I tried querying for those and it didn't work either. @Briggs